# How can I get the counts, as well as the solution bitstring from Qiskit VQE?

Tags: qiskit, vqe

I just set up a Qiskit VQE algorithm and calculated the eigenstates. However, I'm searching now, how to show up the final, most likely solution-bit-string. And/or to print the counts. I actually cannot interpret the eigenstate of the solution found.

Problem to solve: Community-Detection encoded as docplex model, later translated into a Qiskit Quadratic Program

Variable "result" of type `algorithms.minimum_eigen_solvers.vqe.VQEResult`

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for : [see the sample_most_likely function](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/algorithms/05_qaoa.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link!